# Unable to add a row to a table in XML

Tags: jquery, html, xml, css

When my page loads the XML data below is meant to fill the text box and when the user selects 'repaint table' then it should add in a row consisting of the correct criteria. Also if you wanted to copy and paste that again then it should add another row where you can edit things like the color etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>
        <!-- This is a comment tag -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="generic.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var xmlData = "<stock><product><item>1234</item> <description>First item</description><price>12.50</price> </product><product><item>4321</item><description>Second item</description><price>5.99</price></product></stock>";
            paint_table() {}

            $(document).ready(function() {
                if ($('textarea').val().length == 0) {
                    $('textarea').val(xmlData);
                } else {
                    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlData);
                }

                $xml = $(xmlDoc);
                $("#product_table > tbody").empty();

                $xml.find("product").each(function() {    
                    //Process a 'product'
                    var Col0 = $(this).find('item').text();
                    var Col1 = $(this).find('description').text();
                    var Col2 = $(this).find('price').text();
                    $("product_table > tbody").append("<tr><td>" + Col0 +
                        "</td><td>" + Col1 + "</td><td>&pound;" +
                        Col2 + "</td></tr>");

                    $("#product_table > tbody")
                        .find('tr:odd').css("background-color", "red")
                        .end()
                        .find('tr:even').css("background-color", "blue");
                });
            });    
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="product_table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <textarea cols="80"></textarea><br />
        <button>Repaint Table</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 100%;
}

table {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 400px;
}

thead {
    background-color: darkblue;
    color: white;
}

textarea,
button {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle or so..

Comment: yes, 2 mins and I will

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pwmks4x5/

Comment: what is the definition of `paint_table()`?

Comment: I'll link you the file where the tutorial is

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/arh5rol8nyc71a4/Web%20Design%20and%20HCI%20-%20Lab%2017%20-%20XML%20and%20Tables.pdf?dl=0

Comment: please go through the tutorial and update the fiddle..

Comment: no I have done and it's not working